# Running cmd /c from PowerShell with spaces in filepath

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am trying to run the following command in PowerShell

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> cmd /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\vsdevcmd.bat && nuget restore && msbuild mywebapp.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishedProfile=ServerFolderProfile"
```

This produces the error

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command.
```

My paths have spaces and I'm running several commands seperated by && which is messing everything up. I have tried putting quotes all over the place but I can't get it to work.

If i run just the first part of the command

```
cmd /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\vsdevcmd.bat"
```

it works fine. But I can't get the other commands to work too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [docs for `cmd.exe`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html):

> If `/C` or `/K` is specified, then the remainder of the command line is processed as an immediate command in the new shell. Multiple commands separated by the command separator `&` or `&&` are accepted if surrounded by quotes

So I just had to change my command to:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> cmd /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\vsdevcmd.bat" "&&" nuget restore "&&" msbuild mywebapp.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishedProfile=ServerFolderProfile
```

Comment: You should flag your answer as the answer to this question so that it is not left 'unanswered' - if you can.

Comment: @AdamParsons When I try I get a message that says I have to wait until tomorrow. So I will do it then.