# Running cmd /c from a PowerShell ps1 script using Stop-Parsing

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have been stuck on this for ages. I am trying to run the following command from a .ps1 file

```
  cmd --% /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" "&&" nuget restore "&&" msbuild mywebapp.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=ServerFolderProfile
```

But I keep getting the following error

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I figured out how to run the command from a PowerShell window from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53028155/running-cmd-c-from-powershell-with-spaces-in-filepath).

Also, the [Stop-Parsing](https://ss64.com/ps/stop-parsing.html) `--%` symbol requires at least Version 3 of PowerShell and I am running version 5.1.

Comment: version 5 is over 3 powershell wise so thats ok. CMD is a process for shell.  This loks like a mix of shell and powershell. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @ArcSet I am trying to automate deployment of my ASP.NET project. When I push my branch to a remote repo on my network a git hook (post-receive) executes a PowerShell script (which includes the line above) that builds and deployes the app to a folder. All I really need is msbuild.exe to do this, but when I run it from a regular command prompt I get errors and the solution I found was to use the Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio. All VsDevCmd.bat from my command does is set some environment variables that the Developer Command Prompt would use.

Comment: Did you check `Test-Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"`?

Comment: @JosefZ While that didn't solve the original questions, using `Test-Path` did introduce me to a new problem I have to solve. The bat file is on my server, and if I run PowerShell from my local machine from a shared folder on my server, then `Test-Path` fails because it is looking on my local machine. So now I have to figure out how to get the Script to remote into my server, because when I run `Test-Path` directly on my server it passes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about `--%`. Put quotes around the entire commandline you want to run in CMD and escape the nested double quotes around the path to the batch file.

```cs
cmd /c "`"C:\Pro...Cmd.bat`" && nuget restore && msbuild mywebapp.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=ServerFolderProfile"
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm. Of course now I am running into some other problems with my script but at least I got this solved.